# Repeated use of bounties for promotional purposes

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounties

I'm talking about this question specifically: [AutoMapper vs ValueInjecter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663577/automapper-vs-valueinjecter)

The author of ValueInjecter seems to be offering 50 rep bounties repeatedly on the question, presumably just so the question will get more exposure. Now the software looks pretty cool, but this seems like it's not what the bounty system was meant for. While paying reputation to promote a question (and the accepted answer) isn't obviously a bad idea, it is encouraging strange behavior, like adding on another answer "yes, I ALSO like ValueInjecter" to get the new bounty.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Has anyone actually voted to close or mod-flagged the question?  How do you know the OP isn't just a philanthropist, and wants to give his wares (er, rep) away to anyone who provides a decent answer?

Comment: This is not the OP giving the bounty but the accepted answer. Promotion to get more votes? BTW this has been flagged with link to this topic.

Comment: No one has voted to close or flagged the question yet. I don't think he's looking for an answer here since he's already got the accepted answer with 54 votes, which is him explaining the advantages of his software in detail.

Comment: AH, I see now. I'm going to refund the bounty and lock the question.

Comment: @M'vy I meant promotion of his software, ValueInjecter. By promoting the question, people read it, read the accepted answer and download it. That's the only motivation I can think of for the bounties.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bounty refunded, and question locked.

Answer (score 3):

Flag for moderator attention??

Maybe this should be locked or turn to CW I don't know. But this is rather strange indeed.

One has 5x50 of bounty O_o? And given the number of vote on the accepted answer i don't think the topic need quailty improvement.