# Please remove the requirement for increased bounty spend on re-bounties

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, bounties

I just went to make a bounty on a question I previously bountied and found that the minimum rep is now 100.

Please fix this back, so we can put up 50 rep bounties again.  While I've put up larger bounties before, not all questions need that level.

Do you really think we weren't attracting enough attention with the 50 rep bounties?

**EDIT:**  This is now a feature-request to remove the sad feature that Rebecca references that was just implemented, whereby when you bounty a question that you already bountied, it costs you double.

This will only squelch the **main** way that the community has to lobby for their feature-request/change.

While the main need to remove this is on Meta, there doesn't seem to be a good reason to implement this on SO either.  The only way to abuse the 50 rep bounties, is to give a really good answer.  So since the goal of the site is really good answers, is it really abuse?

Comment: Note, that this wasn't documented in the Recent Changes question.

Comment: Wait a minute, I can see 50 rep as a bounty option. Are you trying to offer a *second* bounty on the same question?

Comment: I know I need to go through the RFC2SE and make sure it is current...it's definitely on my list of things to do.

Comment: @Rebecca, I understand busy to-do lists.

Comment: @Rebecca I added this one for you. Busy month! :)

Comment: sorry ... this was abused horribly ... we will not be eliminating this feature.

Comment: Hmmm, Guess not enough people care about their feature-requests to think that re-bounties matter.

Comment: @waffles, no, I don't really think it was abused horribly.  If someone paid 50 rep to get a question featured, and they happened to make a little rep off of it (which was seldom my case), then they deserve it for having a good answer that people would upvote.  There is no way to really __abuse__ it.  It's even less profitable now that questions only get +5 on upvotes.

Comment: @lance this is based on SO abuse of bounties exclusively, we honestly did not consider meta at all in this decision

Comment: @Jeff, well, I've made my point in the comments to waffles and Marc about the term abuse.  I certainly have all the Meta rep I need to afford this, but the newer guys coming on will find this to be limiting on their ability to work their feature requests.

Comment: @Lance If your question is specific to Meta SO, would you mind updating the title to make that clear?

Comment: @Chris, I might, or add the `Meta` tag.  I'm gonna think on it abit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A 50 rep bounty is still possible.  However, if you later put another bounty on the same question, you need to pony up more reputation, doubling each time until the max allowed.

You can read more details about this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105275/140548).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry SE felt that this was necessary.  It will really hamper getting the word out, but I guess the Team is getting tired of people wanting the same things all the time.  I certainly wasn't making a profit on my bounties.

Comment: @Lance - to clarify, this change was not specifically targeted at meta, and does not relate to any opinion about change-requests on meta. It was primarily to avoid abuse on the main (q&a) sites. It doesn't seem unreasonable to keep the logic the same in both main and meta.

Comment: OK, but I don't see the logic calling it abuse, when someone draw attention to what must be a good answer, or they wouldn't get the upvotes to balance out their expenditure.  So the only way they can possibly abuse it would be to give incredibly good answers.

Comment: @Lance ... attention is a limited resource ... taking too much of it is abuse

Comment: @waffles, I definitely agree with you that attention is a limited resource, even if I don't think this was the right solution.  Couldn't we just have figured out an average of what those `abusive` bountiers are making, and then make that the maximum instead of the huge progression?