# How many bounty points I must offer to get an optimal solution?

Tags: support, bounties, unanswered-questions, no-answers

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456472/needed-cfg-for-this-pda) question yesterday.

- It neither got downvoted nor upvoted, but one user voted to close it without explaining the reason.
- I got no answer too.
- **It has only 17 views so far.**
- I think this question is not off topic.

So, for the first time I decided to start a bounty (tomorrow). But I can see many questions are there, which are left unanswered even if they have a bounty of +500.

Being a question which has comparatively rare tags, with lesser views, I know which maximum bounty I should give to this question. And I am ready to spend it, since I feel this question is important for me.

**I don't want to be in a situation where I spend my hard earned reputation, and then don't get an answer after the bounty peroid.**

My questions are....

1. How many bounty points can I give to this question?
2. What if I don't get the answer with in 7 days (active period).

Comment: Can you post a link to the question?

Comment: The one close-vote is `Not a real question`...and I agree with that. What ***is*** your question?

Comment: @Pekka It's there in the first line.

Comment: @Padded Cell My question is how could I get CFG for the given PDA. and that is the title of the question.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT - hiding the question in the title of the post is a good way of making sure people miss the question. Combine that with  a question that amounts to "please do it for me" is good way to turn away a significant chunk of readers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How much bounty points can I give to this question?

The general maximum is 500 points, but of course you have to have those points to start the bounty. I think the maximum you can start right now is 350 points.

> But I doesn't want to be in a situvation where I spent my hardearned reputations but I doesnt get an answer.

There is always the risk of you losing your points when starting a bounty - if there hasn't been a satisfactory answer after a week, you will not get your points back.

Comment: If someone senior on SO who knows the subject matter can confirm that this is a good and answerable question, I'm willing to sponsor a 350 bounty.

Comment: thank you for your sponser. I am ready to spend 300 reputations of mine. And I am about to start the bounty tomorrow. And thanks a lot for your willingness and good heart.

Answer (score 8):

I would give a bouty of 50. It's enough to make your question appear on the “featured” tab. A higher bounty won't give it more attention.

By giving a higher bounty, you will motivate a few more users. But bounties, especially high ones, also attract poor answers, given in the hope that you'll settle for an inferior answer, or perhaps click the wrong answer when awarding the bounty. A higher bounty will attract more answers, but not necessarily more high-quality answers.

An advantage of sticking to a bounty of 50 is that as of a few days ago, if you want to give a second bounty, [you must double the amount](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639), and so on exponentially. So if you're worried of not getting a satisfactory answer in a week, it's better to start small.

A bounty will give your question a little more attention and bring a little more incentive to potential answerers, but it's by no means a sure-fire way of getting an answer. Do whatever you can to make the question clear and appealing to the people who might know the answer.

- Your question contains a single sentence followed by an image. Try to explain what you want in words, in addition to the image. There's some text in the image: transcribe it as text, so that it comes up in searches.
- Your text is often not clear. Your last sentence (in the image) is unfinished. Even if English is not your native language, aim to be at least comprehensible. Check your spelling (<strike>consturct</strike>, <strike>grammer</strike>). Define your abbreviations: I'm sure many viewers thought you were asking for a [control flow graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) whereas from the context you presumably mean a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).
- Since this is a homework question, show what you've tried (even if it's “I tried this technique and got nowhere”). Update the question whenever you make progress on your own.

Comment: Good points about the new incremental system.

Answer (score 3):

Zero. If you post a clear, on-topic, question, and someone knows the answer, it's nearly certain that you will get an answer. If your question is unclear, or if it is off-topic, or if no one knows the answer, an entire mutiny of bounties isn't going to make an answer appear from outer space.