# Why is there a huge horizontal scrollbar on this question?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was just looking at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105275) in Firefox 8.0 and noticed that it has a *huge* horizontal scrollbar, as shown in the following screenshot, despite an absence of content to the right. Is this a bug?

[image: Question with a large horizontal scrollbar]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Jeremy (the one who put the bounty on the question) left a bounty remark that put in a ridiculous amount of non-breaking spaces (actual non-breaking space characters, not the entities `&nbsp;`) resulting in what you see there.  View the source of the page and you'll see what I mean.

‮(-: We could be malicious with the content of our posts if we wanted to since we allow unicode pretty much anywhere...

Comment: Oh, you're right! Interesting. I wonder if that was intentional or automatically inserted for some reason. In either case, non-breaking spaces in bounty remarks probably shouldn't cause this behavior...

Comment: +1: For whatever reason, despite the `<p>` not going outside of its container, it still widened the window pane. Removing it fixed the problem.

Comment: I believe they're just normal spaces, not non-breaking ones.

Comment: @JohnFlatness: Oh, they were non-breaking.

Comment: @balpha So...was this actually a bug, or expected behavior given the non-breaking spaces in the bounty remark?

Comment: @Chris: Probably expected, the remark has been removed from the post now.

Comment: @Chris: I put in a bunch of non-breaking spaces to see what would happen. My browser seemed to ignore them; I'm pretty sure it didn't display like this to me.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Ah, cool, thanks. I'll mention which browser I used in the question (it may be a Firefox-specific issue).

Comment: @Chris: Re "actually a bug", that's more of the "stop doing that" variety. There'll always be ways for people to be funny, so if you fix one of these, there'll be something else.