# Minimum bounty seems too steep?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I have a difficult question, that I have gone to extensive effort to answer for myself, and I had placed a (fairly high) bounty on it in the past which didn't result in any answer.

That was almost four months ago and I've just discovered some new info that narrows down the question quite a lot.

I edited my question, and would like to place another bounty. But it only allows a bounty of 500! That's a lot of rep for me, I think it's too much and perhaps the minimum bounty increase algorithm should be reconsidered.

The question is basically trying to find a workaround for what looks like an operating system or API bug in a fairly new feature of OS X.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/134300) is when the doubling of successive bounties was implemented.

Comment: Which question?

Comment: Are there enough changes in the question to warrant asking a new question, while linking back to the original?

Comment: I assume [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407530/confusing-encoding-exception-in-nstextstorage) is the question in question? There, have an upvote. Not that that gets you very far on the road to 500...

Comment: I don't think this counts as abuse, and  I like your question. I put a 200 rep bounty on it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @BenLee, and yes that is the question I had in mind. But my main reason for asking here is I think maybe the minimum bounty threshold should gradually drop down over time, given the goal is to avoid spamming the bounty system? It should be possible to put a bounty of 50 on a question that still hasn't been answered after four months, but has new info.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the anti-abuse method they use is over-broad and will prevent a lot of perfectly reasonable bounties. A gradual decrease in the min bounty over time would work, but I also think that it makes even more sense to just never require a bounty to cost more than 250 (allow it, but *never* require it) -- I think that would cover abuse cases pretty well.

Comment: As far as giving you the bounty, I do think your question on SO is good and I agree with your position here, but I also figured this was a perfect opportunity for me to go for the Altruist and Investor badges =).

Comment: This is a pretty narrow edge case.

You already placed a +250 bounty on that question, without results.  Clearly it's time to raise the ante.