# I can only offer a 500 rep bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum bounty seems too steep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127000/minimum-bounty-seems-too-steep)
>   [Clever bounty reputation hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack)
>   [Minimum bounty on a question is now 100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep)

I recently found more information about [a question I asked some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446768/highstock-scrollbar-doesnt-work-in-svg-foreignobject). To re-kindle interest, I was going to offer a bounty (again) but I'm seeing 500 rep as the only option for how large of a bounty I want to offer.

Is this by design?

Comment: Yes. If you want to offer a larger bounty, you'll have to split it.

Comment: No, I want to offer a smaller bounty!! It's literally the *only* option.

Comment: @Richard: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/134300

Comment: This is really more of a duplicate of this question: [Minimum bounty seems too steep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127000/minimum-bounty-seems-too-steep)

Comment: @The Establishment - Agreed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you set a bounty for a question, [you can only set a bounty ***GREATER*** (and double) than the previous bounty that you had already set](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/155556).

So since you had already [set a bounty for **250**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9446768/revisions) the only bounty you can now set is the next amount (which is also the greatest amount) of **500**.