# Adding more bounty after bounty has expired

Tags: feature-request, bounties, expired-bounty

I asked the following question about a week or 2 ago.

[Paypal SandBox IPN always returns INVALID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746644/paypal-sandbox-ipn-always-returns-invalid)

I added bounty, which expired.  Now I want to add more bounty to the question, but I am not getting an option to do so.

Is it not possible to add further bounty to a question which has already had bounty?

Comment: I didn't read through the exhaustive commentary on the question to know if I'm asking something that's already been asked, but have you considered appealing to PayPal support for this?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Yes, I've added a question to the paypal developer site, x.com and have not been given an answer yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add a second bounty, you will have to add a bounty of [double the value of your previous bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639). Since that appears to have been a bounty of 200, your new bounty should be 400. You don't have enough rep left to do so.

Edit:
Given that you actually set a bounty of 400 but did not award it, half of it got awarded to the eligible answer given the conditions outlined in ["How does the bounty system work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). (Which explains the bounty value of 200 I mentioned before)

> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty
> starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be
> automatically awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an
> answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows:
>
> - The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2 If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.

The 400 bounty does suggest that, even if you had enough rep to do so, you will no longer be able to set another bounty on the question. 500 is the maximum if I recall correctly.

Comment: The original bounty was 400, and 200 got assigned automatically.  The system seems flawed, i.e. answers which don't solve the problem get bounty assigned to them automatically, in this case 200, and the remaining 200 disappears...

Comment: There is nothing flawed about that. It's how the system works. If you don't assign it, half the bounty gets assigned automatically. A bounty is not meant as a guarantee for you to get the right answer, but as a means to get attention for your question. And if you already awarded a bounty of 400, you can no longer add another bounty. 400 is the maximum if I recall correctly.

Comment: It seems flawed in that people get rewarded when their answer does not solve the problem.  I would understand a partial bounty award if the answer partially solved the problem, but in this case, the answer did not solve the problem at all.

Comment: Once again, the bounty is meant to get attention for your question, which you apparently got. If you don't get a correct answer and award the bounty yourself, half of it is automatically awarded to the answer which meets the conditions as listed under "What is automatic awarding?" in [this Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: In that case, why have options when assigning bounty, i.e. to get more attention, looking for an answer from an authoritative source, etc etc.  Doesn't look like `attention` is the only reason based on the options given.

Comment: @Bart I'm not sure what the max is (and I'm too lazy to look it up) but I think it's greater than 400. [I've received 500 at least once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212).

Comment: @AaronBertrand That's what I said, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, in your comment you said 400. I posted my comment before I saw your edit, where you correctly said 500.

Comment: Ah, I see. Haha, you are of course right. Thanks for that anyway. I was too lazy before but looked it up just now. ;)

Comment: @oshirowanen Even with the other options the bounty is there to raise awareness that you would like an answer, authoritative source, or whatever else. Bounties are like advertisements. You hope to get an appropriate response from them. They are by no means a guarantee that you will.