# No suitable answer on a question with a bounty set

Tags: support, bounties

What should I do in this situation?

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549455/asp-net-mvc4-bundle-for-less-files-not-being-rendered-when-debug-set-to-false) and all three answers so far are not helpful at all - with two of them being just plain bounty-baiting.

Can I extend the bounty date or should I close the question?

What do I do in these cases?

Comment: You can put another bounty on it when the current one expires. But you won't get the rep back from the first one.

Comment: And maybe you could expand the explanation on the question. In addition to the new bounty.

Comment: Is it kosher if I write an answer to my own question? I figured out why it didn't work properly and none of the answers were the solution.

Comment: @Serg yes, you can answer your own question, but I am virtually certain you can't award yourself the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do in this situation?

If you think none of the answers are deserving of the bounty you placed, you do not have to award it.  In this case, at the present time, Community♦ will *not* [award half of the amount automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) as none of the answers after the bounty was started have got a score of 2 or more.

> Can I extend the bounty date

No, however you can start another bounty once the grace period at the end of the current bounty has ended.  [You will be required to put up at least double the amount you did previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639).

> should I close the question?

Not if it's a valid question!  In addition to this questions with an active bounty can not be closed.

For more information you should see the [FAQ on bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).