# Is it OK to put multiple bounties on the same question, if you don't really understand the existing answers?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I'm wondering if it's bad form, to put multiple bounties on a question on StackOverflow proper, because you did not get an answer that makes it *click* with you? i.e there are existing answers, but they seem to be lacking in some way.

The main concern is that it would possibly take away traffic from newer, first-time bounties. Or is it OK to keep adding bounties ?

Comment: You are allowed to. Serious abuse is mitigated by forcing you to [offer double the amount each time when you put an additional bounty on a question that you have already bountied](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/134300).

Comment: @JeremyBanks- Hmm, OK - but actually it seems there's a limit at 500? I.e if I put a 500 bounty, it doesn't offer '1000' the next time.  I guess 500 is limit. cool thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If none of the answers on a question, despite receiving multiple bounties helped you, then feel free to add your own (or another). Just be very specific about the type of answer you feel the question needs in order to be helpful to the broadest possible audience. As Jeremy [noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176434/is-it-ok-to-put-multiple-bounties-on-the-same-question-if-you-dont-really-unde#comment529704_176434), it might cost you if you've previously placed a bounty on the same question, and there are limits to the system. But, this isn't as much of a concern if you're putting a bounty a question asked by someone else.

That said, if the answers to a question are already bordering on encyclopedic, it might be a sign that you'll just need to do a little more research and learning independently. For instance, if all answers to a question contain bit manipulation hacks, and you don't understand bit manipulation, it's better to go read up on that elsewhere - explaining that in depth might be way out of the scope for a suitable answer to the question.

Use your discretion but no - it's not categorically frowned upon, and might even create an opportunity for a new user that is very familiar with the topic to unlock more features even faster.

Comment: Understood,  Thank You Very Much!