# Do questions with bounties get more attention/replies?

Tags: discussion, bounties

Just curious as to whether adding karma bounties to questions gets it more attention from users. What do you think?

And if you saw a question with a nice bounty on it (say 50+) are you more likely to read that question and give it a go? Or does interest in a question matter more? Trade offs?

Would love to hear thoughts, comments, etc.

Comment: Well, there will be people who have the featured tab bookmarked, so it's probably very likely. The most experienced users also end up rep capped and can go bounty hunting if they want.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)