# Do questions with bounties actually get more views and attention?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I've been browsing through a variety of sites on SE and noticed that questions with bounties do not seem to get more views, answers, or upvotes than those without bounties (except for a few examples that seem to get quite a few of all three).

Does pairing a bounty with a question actually cause users to view it more and give it more attention? I would've thought that getting +100 reputation for answering a question would cause many people to flock to said question, but I haven't observed such a phenomenon (perhaps I just haven't seen enough examples of questions with bounties?). Granted, I am still fairly new to SE and its websites, so excuse my lack of experience.

Comment: Also: [Do questions with bounties get more attention/replies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186202/21960)