# The help center entry on bounty fails to state the doubling minimum with each further bounty added by the same user

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, help-center

The [help center on bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) currently only states

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

This lacks the [information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639) that the minimum amount for a bounty on the *same* question by the *same* user **doubles everytime**, i.e. it's 100 for the second bouty, 200 for the third bounty, 400 for the fourth and so on (well, and so on is relative, since the maximum of 500 is still place, and I haven't yet tested whether a fifth bounty will have to be 500 or simply cannot be done. But I digress...). So the text should be extended into something like

> To [avoid overly promotional bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639), if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50). Also, if you are offering a bounty *again* on the same question, the minimum spend doubles *each time*.

Comment: "minimum spend" seems like a weird sort of phrasing too, but that might just be me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a new bullet point that discloses the doubling minimum for multiple bounties.

Comment: That was quick :-) So what happens with the fifth bounty? Will it always be 500, 800 or impossible?