# confused by "question bounty" and "normal bounty"

Tags: support, bounties

I'm not using bounties that much, but on this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

These two points confuse me:

*"Questions may only have one active question bounty at any given time."*

*"Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, ..."*

What is the difference?

Comment: Yeah, I think "question bounty" is a redundant term. What other type of bounties are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple bounties on a question, just not at the same time.

That is - you can offer another bounty on a question that you have already offered a bounty on only if there is no currently active bounty on it.

Bounties can only be applied to questions, so in this regard a "normal bounty" is the same as a "question bounty".

Comment: If you offer another bounty on the same question you also have to increase the value from the previous bounty, correct?

Comment: @TronicZomB - Yes, that's how bounties work. You must offer more reputation than the last time.

Comment: @Oded is there any post that says why? If rewarded answer became obsolete, why should I pay more for more recent one? It's the same question and same effort as it was last time, after all.

Comment: @Mołot - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639