# Can I change which answer I chose to award the bounty to after I've done so?

Tags: support, bounties

I offered a bounty to a question and there is a good answer. If I give the bounty to that answer, could I change the bounty to another better answer within the seven days that the bounty is offered?

Comment: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @MicRO I asked this because I didn't see the answer there. If it's answered there, could you say to me where is the answer exactly?

Comment: Did I tell that it is already answered there?

Comment: @MicRO So why do you put that comment? I am just curious. Is it because my question it's related (I'm new in Meta, I don't know how this works really) ?

Comment: [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: On Meta, we frequently close support questions as duplicates of canonical questions in the FAQ. The one MicRO picked out is the obvious duplicate candidate. But like you said, this question isn't actually answered there, so this really is not a duplicate...at least not yet. Perhaps this answer *should* be added to the FAQ, which would make this a duplicate. Either way, you should not feel insulted or offended at having your question closed as a duplicate. It is just our way of keeping the site clean and getting you the answers you're looking for as quickly as possible.

Comment: That said, I have no idea why he posted "How do comments work?". That does just seem rather rude...

Comment: *"I asked this because I didn't see the answer there"*, then please next time add such detail to the question, as part of [*"Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks.

Comment: @Pigueiras Hi Pigueiras, please be patient. Posting a link to a page where similar or helpful discussions are there didn't always mean that this is an exact duplicate of the post mentioned in the comment, neither do you new people are stupid (as you mentioned a while ago). All that i meant is to help you reading similar posts and read reviews from experts. Please don't  drag me into unnecessary discussions , first check what are comments meant for. Thanks

Comment: @Pigueiras I know its you who downvoted two of my questions. Please don't show such indecent behavior in SO.

Comment: Accusing people without evidence is also considered "indecent behavior", @MicRO. You have no way of knowing it was Pigueiras that downvoted your questions. Downvotes are anonymous. C'mon kids, please stop fighting.

Comment: @MicRO You can flag to moderator if you think that those downvotes are  unjustified. I have better things to do than just to downvote you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot change a bounty once it has been allocated.

But why would you want to? What's the hurry in assigning the bounty to an answer? The whole point of raising a bounty on your question is to attract attention, and hopefully good answers. There's no reason to settle for the first one that rolls in; give it time and see if you get anything better. At the end of the bounty period, you can look at what answers you have and choose the best/most helpful one.

It's not like the person is going to delete their answer in the meantime, so what have you lost by waiting?

Technically, you could go ahead and assign the bounty to this answer, and then if another answer is posted, you could start a *second* bounty to reward that answer. But this has a couple of problems. First, once the bounty is assigned, you lose the major advantage of having an active bounty: your question appearing in the "featured" tab and attracting the attention of answerers. Second, [the starting amount for a bounty goes up each time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639), so you'll end up having to slice off more of your reputation for this.

Comment: Do I receive a notification if the period ended?

Comment: @Pigueiras I believe so, I think you get a notification 24 hours in advance. Either on the site or by email. I'm not actually sure about that, though, having never used the system myself.

Comment: There's a notification 3 days before and another one 24 hours before it expires.

Comment: Theres also a 24 hour grace period after the bounty ends to award it before half of it is auto awarded

Comment: "The whole point of raising a bounty on your question is to attract attention, and hopefully good answers." If that is the case, then why when starting a bounty, one of the reason options is "Reward existing answer - One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."?