# If your first bounty is bigger than the minimal 50 points, then the minimal bounty should not increase

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Currently if you post a second bounty, it has to be twice the previous bounty. 
So if you start a bounty of 150 reputation, the next one must be 300 or more.

I think it is unfair. The double is to prevent endless bounty periods. However, if the first bounty is already high, then the double is not needed to prevent endless bounty periods.

I think the only thing neccesary is that the new bounty is at least the old one. So you can't follow a 150 rep bounty with a 100 rep bounty.

---

In short what I propose:

- When you post a bounty, the minimal amount of rep spent is 50 for the first, 100 for the second, 200 for the third, 400 for the fourth and 500 for any further bounties. As usual, when you've posted an answer,  the minimal amount of rep spent is 100 for the first, 200 for the second, 400 for the third and 500 for any further bounties.
- The bounty must be at least as high (perhaps higher?) as all other bounties you've already posted on the question.
- In mathematical terms, the minimal bounty award is 
  max(f*2<sup>number of bounties started</sup>*50, previous bounty) 
   
  where f is one if you haven't posted an answer, and f is two if you have.

---

In fact, this is how I would understand what is written in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). However it is certainly not the case. (On this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1376622/236048), I can only start a bounty of 300 reputation of more despite having started only one bounty worth 150 reputation).

This will also be helpful when you want to reward two good answers, because using this rule, you can start two bounties worth 100 rep each and thus give the answers both the same amount.

---

Examples of things that are allowed:

- 150, 150, 200, 400: total rep spent: 900, as opposed to 750 minimal for 4 bounties.
- 50, 200, 200: total rep spent: 450, as opposed to 350 minimal for 3 bounties.
- 300, 300, 300: total rep spent: 900, as opposed to 350 minimal for 3 bounties.

Examples of things that are not allowed:

- 50, 50, because second bounty < 100
- 100, 100, 150, because third bounty < 200
- 200, 200, 200, 200, because fourth bounty < 400
- 500, 250 because second bounty < first bounty

Comment: Looks like we need MathJax enabled on Meta now :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I was slightly irritated when I noticed it was not. But I guess it works fine.

Comment: I don't actually understand the difference as to what it is now. `When you post a bounty, the minimal amount of rep spent is 50 for the first, 100 for the second, 200 for the third, 400 for the fourth and 500 for any further bounties` Is that not what happens now?? I think I'm missing something - let me check

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ No, if I now post a 150 rep bounty as the first bounty, the next bounty must be 300. Under my proposal, the next bounty only has to be 150.

Comment: ahh -- okay I get you - keep on doubling *from the original* 50 rather than *your* previous one.

Comment: As for the original reasoning: [“Abusing” bounties for unlimited profit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639).

Answer (score 3):

The [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) says:

> the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty

So the last bounty was 150. 150 * 2 = 300. So 300 is the new minimum bounty to start. In my opinion this is exactly what it says it does.

Maybe the wording actually meant:

> 50 for the first, 50*2=100 for the second, 100*2=200 for the third, 200*2=400 for the fourth and 500 for any further bounties

That is just an example of how the steps could be, choosing another opening bounty changes this.

Comment: But I also quote form the help center: (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

Comment: But you started with 150, so that is the new starting point.

Comment: Suppose we have a variable minimumSpend. It starts at 50. When you want to start a subsequent bounty, it doubles. That is my understanding of what the help center says. I guess it is open to interpretation, but I don't think this system is fair.

Comment: No, that 50 is just the minimum starting point.

Comment: Sorry, I just read it as 'bring it back to the documentation', while I argue it is already, so 'feature request already implemented'.

Comment: No, I request it to be changed. But the help center is not my main point. The main points are: It won't make it easier to start an endless bounty periond and it is possible to reward two answers with the same amount of rep.

Answer (score -1):

> The double is to prevent endless bounty periods.

It's also because of a necessity to make the bounty exclusive, and the increment for each subsequent bounty needs to be substantial enough to make the reward enticing where the previous one was not.

It would be pointless posting subsequent bounties in increments of 5 (so 50, then 55, then 60, etc) if no-one answered at 50 then 5 more is not likely to make any difference.

We cannot have the incremental value too low as this would bring about too many bounties on the same post, and too many total posts with live bounties. We cannot have it too high as then we might as well just leave it as it is.

So what do we increment by?

**Exclusive**
Bounty needs to be *expensive* so it's *exclusive*, and this includes a high incremental value, otherwise if it was cheap then many users would just shove bounty after bounty on their questions and then there'd be tens of thousands of bounty questions. This would essentially just shift the current "unanswered/questions" area to "bounty" area, but now at a cost - which arguably makes the bounty system *more expensive* than it currently is as you get less exclusive visibility.

Also consider that by doing this we greatly complicate the bounty system, which is currently pretty useful and simple to use and understand.

---

> I think the only thing neccesary is that the new bounty is at least
>   the old one.

So I can post 50 then 50 *again*? How many times can I do this? It has to be limited otherwise you introduce *infinite* bounties to the same post, and lose the *exclusivity* of bounty.

---

I honestly do not see what your feature request is trying to achieve. You haven't really explained *why* the current system needs changing. I presume because you want to "spend" less, but as explained above this would not be a good thing and would actually make bounties become expensive based on their loss of exclusivity.

What is wrong with having to double your previous bounty?

---

> This will also be helpful when you want to reward two good answers,
>   because using this rule, you can start two bounties worth 100 rep each
>   and thus give the answers both the same amount.

Well I see this as a separate thing altogether, and perhaps would be useful as a *new* function with specifics away from the normal bounty system.
It would not change the way the current bounty system works, and instead adds a new option where we can *specifically*:

- Add a new bounty and immediately apply to a current answer

i.e. The question does not go into "Featured" for 7 days of visibility, you just immediately give rep to an answer(s).

Though I believe there is already a feature request for this (or similar)

Comment: -1. You misunderstood it completely. You can't do 50, 50. Quote from the post: When you post a bounty, the minimal amount of rep spent is 50 for the first, 100 for the second. You can do 100, 100 though, which is more than the 50, 100 that is currently allowed.  However, with the current system if your first bounty is 100, then the second must be 200.

Comment: I added some examples, please reconsider your answer and vote.

Comment: "*You misunderstood it completely. You can't do 50, 50*" You're entitled to your -1 on my answer, but if it's simply for reasons as per your comment then I dispute it, as I clearly quoted from your question "*I think the only thing neccesary is that the new bounty is at least the old one*". "At least the old one" means just that, the old one is included and thus you state that 50 then 50 is valid. If you do not mean that or do not want people to think we should allow a repeat of "the old one" then do not state such in your proposal :)

Comment: No I didn't. Read "In short what I propose:" There are clearly two criteria.

Comment: You also stated this to ᔕᖺᘎᕊ in your comments "*No, if I now post a 150 rep bounty as the first bounty, the next bounty must be 300. Under my proposal, the next bounty only has to be 150*" which also shows you mean 150 then 150, so posting the same bounty twice.The fact you go on to state "double previous" is simply a contradiction of previous statements and so confusing. Maybe it's just me (and  ᔕᖺᘎᕊ) but it seems unclear what you propose, and why.

Comment: Your examples are more confusing. Again, perhaps it's just me, but I have no idea why or what you mean by these: "*150, 150, 200, 400*" and "*50, 200, 200*" and "*300, 300, 300*". there are repeat bounty amounts but no explanation as to why. Seems a chunky change and so should be explained not only "how" but your reasoning behind why this would be better etc.

Comment: It was an unfortunate wording. However, please read "In short what I propose:" and the examples.

Comment: hmm, after re-reading it a few times, it's potentially more clear. So if I don't place 50 or 100, I can place 150 then 150? then 200 and then 400. This seems quite complicated for very little improvement. In fact the only improvement I can see is you ability to use the same figure twice, which seems to be in line with your want to reward two answers with the same bounty. If this is the case, then your suggestion is not an improvement nor does it resolve anything, it simply adds something new, which is what I implied at the end of my (-1) answer :)

Comment: If you edit your answer to remove some erroneous parts I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Nah, my answer is accurate as I see it, and your downvote perfectly legit based on your personal opinions. nw :)