# Help text for successive bounties on same question is unclear

Tags: feature-request, bounties, help-center, wording

I'd like to suggest an improvement to the text in the [bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), in the section on offering successive bounties on the same question:

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, **the minimum spend doubles** with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

What this doesn't say is that the minimum spend on a second bounty is really **double the actual value of the previous bounty**. I discovered this to my detriment when I wanted to place a follow-up bounty to reward another answer. The original bounty was for 250. The only bounty it would let me place after that was 500. I was planning to place a 200 reputation reward bounty but that was not possible. If the most deserving answer got 250, it doesn't feel right award 500 to an answer that's also good and valuable but required less effort or provides less value.

To clarify, I don't take issue with this practice as it will only happen rarely and there's a good reason for the doubling, see: ["Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)

But even on that thread announcing the change, they talk of minimum spend and no mention is made of the fact that the minimum spend becomes *double the actual spend* of the previous bounty. **Assuming that this isn't a bug, the help text should be updated to clarify this.**

Comment: Good point. My suggestion: "Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend for each bounty is double of the previous bounty. (e.g. if the first was 50 reputation, the minimum for the second is 100, if the first was 250, the second can be only 500, and so on)."

Comment: (and for the record, this can't really be a "bug". Wording bug is typo, grammar mistakes, etc.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Given that the wording is unclear to me on the thread announcing the change, I wasn't sure if this behaviour was working as intended or not. Since the bug tag covered "mistakes" as well I figured this was close to a bug than any of the other tags.

Comment: Interestingly, the situation on [the question that prompted this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71644/translating-research-into-a-resume) has semi-resolved itself as the person to whom I awarded the bounty has now started one of his own to reward one of the other answers. :)

Comment: Yeah, that person asked in [chat for advice](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5139867#5139867). Cheers!