# Is the minimum bounty now double your previous bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I wanted to add an extra bounty to a question I had already bountied (at 100 rep) to make its reward comparable to a very similar question I had also bountied.  I wanted to add another 150, but the minimum allowed is now 200.

Out of curiosity I tried to add a bounty to the other question that I had already bountied at 250, and its minimum was 500.

Is this an intentional change or was it always like this?  Is this a bug?

Comment: TL;DR: yes it is on purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)

Comment: no, it's been like that for 10 years

Comment: Thanks all for the answers.  Searching through the top suggestions (at least the first 30-50) did not turn up the linked questions.