# Don't systematically double the minimum amount to offer for a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties

> "if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum
> spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first
> bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on)".

Since the amount of several of the bounties I have been offering (in the intention of drawing more attention to my questions) has just vanished without any profit to anyone, I prefer offering bounties in order to **reward an existing answer**.

In this case, some times after this bounty explicitly awarded, it happens that another valuable answer is posted to that same question.

I do would like to **equally** reward for that new work but just cannot offer less than two times the value I had awarded to the other answer. I think it would be just unfair!

Therefore, I suggest that the system should take into account the reason for offering the bounty and, in the particular case of rewarding an existing answer, does not apply the double minimum spend requirement.

Comment: I understand your request but the reason we do this is to prevent people from perpetually bountying a question. Exempting any of the bounty reasons would leave a loophole where someone could get attention for a question by using the "wrong" bounty reason.

Comment: The bounty reason, currently, has no meaning. Nothing enforce it. The only way to prevent abuse as Catija mentioned is ask the bounty owner to choose existing answer when starting the bounty, then let them award only to that answer. That's pretty complex change that isn't likely to happen.

Comment: Thanks @Catija for answering. I appreciate your point but, wouldn't this sort of abuse be expected marginal and, considering that SE apparently gets some bot for efficiently detecting abuses in downvotings, couldn't repeated abuses in the bounty stuff be as efficiently detected ?

Comment: You should [read the history of what happened and why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)

Comment: @MC68020 Sure - anything like what you say or Shadow says is possible but neither currently exists, which makes this ask significantly bigger than merely removing the restriction. And once solutions start to get bigger, we have to allocate more resources and decide the issue is more important than other issues. While I understand your frustration, and I see some utility in finding another option, when I consider the broader concerns we have, I can't see us investing time in this any time soon.

Comment: @Catija : Fair enough and thanks again for your intelligent (open-minded) attention :-)

Comment: FWIW, you _can_ apply the same bounty amount to multiple different answers... so long as you start at 500 :-)

Comment: A way to implement this without allowing the abuse that the current system is designed to prevent would be adding a feature for the bounty poster to choose to split the reward manually between posts (it can split automatically depending on certain criteria but the bounty poster has almost no control over this) _or_ allow the bounty poster the option to choose, _at the time of posting the bounty_ an option to award a bounty of the specified amount to _multiple answers_, with the option to specify up to, say, 3 answers that they want to award.

Comment: CC @Catija something to add to the bottom of the backlog, perhaps ^ :-) The latter option would probably be better because someone could feel abused if the bounty poster up and split a 100 bounty they were gaming for into two 50 bounties.